# The stunning footage of neutral currents, first observation of a neutrino: Knowledge needed

Tags: neutrinos, experimental-technology, leptons

First of all, this question is purely motivated by curiosity.

I call upon the community's knowledge on the matter. Following the link below, you can see the image of "A lepton event - a neutrino interacting with a electron and emerging as a neutrino" which is said to be the "first observation of "neutral currents" in the Gargamelle heavy liquid bubble chamber".
[image]

It may not be the first observation of a lepton, anyway, this is not the purpose of this post:

Does anyone know what is the nature of the black dots on the picture due to ? Are there a physical phenomena resulting from the characteristics of the liquid that could explain such patterns? Or is it just optical "noise" ?

(One can see a characteristic electron-positron signature pattern on the left, if it helps in any way)

Thank you

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/60894/