# What are these arcs in bubble chamber photos?

Tags: particle-physics, elementary-particles, bubbles

In photos such as this one,

[image: http://imgc.allpostersimages.com/images/P-473-488-90/72/7295/K23O100Z/posters/patrice-loiez-particle-tracks.jpg]

or [this one](http://www.interactions.org/imagebank/images/CE0057H.jpg) (too large to fit inside post), what are the highly frenzied arcs that are really prominent in these photos?

Are they simply physical walls in/of the chamber, and the activity along them, a result of the incoming beam interacting with such walls? Or some other aspect of the chamber that interferes with the contained liquid?

Maybe it's something happening at a different distance down the chamber from the cleanly photographedd particle trails?

Comment: To be clear, are you referring to the single most prominent arc in each picture?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/191100/the-stunning-footage-of-neutral-currents-first-observation-of-a-neutrino-knowl http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/60894/explain-background-pattern-in-particle-tracing-image Interesting to get two such questions in about a week, BTW.

Comment: It is pretty clear to me that in the linked image, at least, you are seeing through to the structure of the rear wall as per [my answer to 60894](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/60901/520). The one included in the post is not so clear, but there are the same concentric features which suggest it may be more of the same.

Comment: Regarding the first question - yes I am curious about the single most prominent arcs :)

Comment: I had read both those two questions before posting mine but didn't notice they were also so recent :D

Thanks for the answer dmckee. Now you point it out, I can notice the slightly misaligned segments along the big blue arcs. Much appreciated.